# Symfony 3.4 - How to decorate the UrlGenerator

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I want to decorate the Symfony UrlGenerator class.

I've added this to the services.yml but my AppBundle\Service\UrlGenerator class is ignored:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator: ~

my.url_generator:
    class: AppBundle\Service\UrlGenerator
    decorates: Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator
    arguments: ['@my.url_generator.inner']
    public:    false
```

Now, I know I can achieve this by overriding some options for router but this is depreciated now I think:

```
router.options.generator_class: AppBundle\Service\UrlGenerator
router.options.generator_base_class: AppBundle\Service\UrlGenerator
```

However it works. I wonder is there any way to decorate the UrlGenerator instead? Also, how to add the ParameterBag to the decorating class?

Comment: Your definition seems fine according to the official documentation. Can you share your `AppBundle\Service\UrlGenerator` class?

Comment: Have you tried assigning your UrlGenerator to the Interface? Check `bin/console debug:container 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface'`

Comment: Sorry guys I have abandoned this path. Resolved my initial problem different way (not decorating the UrlGenerator).